# QVD to CSV conversion row count mismatch

Tags: csv, qlikview

I am using Qlikviw x64 Personal Edition to load QVD files and convert them to a CSV file via script editor

#### Code snippet

```
LOAD * FROM
[C:\Projects\.....\Calendar.qvd]
(qvd);

STORE Calendar INTO [C:\Projects\.....\Calendar.csv]

(txt, delimiter is ',');
```

I find a mismatch in row counts between the QVD and CSV files (countQVD < countCSV) on doing a quick QC. Note this happens on QVD files (~13MB).

Anyone with similar experience? Any idea what can be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I was using Notepad++ where I noticed the issue. But later I opened the file in other editors, the counts matched.

To sum-up it was not an issue with QVD to CSV conversion, but is some sort of a Notepad++ issue.